# oracle LIKE statement conversion?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that I am trying to run and instead of having to type in this string multiple times. Is there a way I can just dump in the numbers?

```
select *
from program_errors
where program_programs like '%program' 
or key111 like '%No -> 49391250'
and key111 like '%No -> 50130037'
and key111 like '%No -> 50804475'
and key111 like '%No -> 51003148'
and key111 like '%No -> 51053053'
;
```

All I would like to do would be to insert the numbers you see in the set of 'strings' into something (maybe the 'IN' clause or 'HAVING' clause) and it bring back the data. The above statement works for my program but I was wondering if anyone knew a more efficient way of doing this. Is there a way to change the key111 to an int?

Comment: take a peek at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm

Comment: you are restricting results with `AND` - how can that possibly work, different patterns cannot all match at the same time? and yes, you could convert a substring of the key111 content to a number if the values are constructed consistently, but it will not be indexable.

Comment: the oracle document you showed me was a good find! Also I had to change to 'or' instead. I messed up

Comment: yeah, you should be able to write a single regular expression to match "%No -> [0-9]{8}" for example, something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your numbers could be of unknown length but always follow "No ->" you could use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`  :

select *
from program_errors
where program_programs like '%program' 
and regexp_substr(key111,'No -> ([0-9]*)',1,1,'',1) in (49391250,50130037,.....);

requires oracle 11g or greater. see doco for meaning of parameters
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm#SQLRF06303

Answer (score 0):

If you know numbers are of 8 digits in each row then you can do :

```
select *
from program_errors
where program_programs like '%program' 
and substr(key111,-8) in (49391250,50130037,.....);
```

Comment: Glad to know that :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a few values you're searching for, you can create a CTE:

```
with keys as (
  select '49391250' as key from dual
  union all select '50130037' from dual
  union all select '50804475' from dual
  union all select '51003148' from dual
  union all select '51053053' from dual
)
select p.*
from program_errors p
where p.program_programs like '%program'
union
select p.*
from program_errors p
join keys on p.key111 like '%No -> ' || keys.key;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way we normally did here is use the excel formula to generate the repeated sql section:

```
Column A                  Column B    Column C   Column D
    Key111 like '%No ->   49391250    '          A1&B1&C1
and key111 like '%No ->   50130037    '          A2&B2&C2
and key111 like '%No ->   50804475    '          A3&B3&C3
and key111 like '%No ->   51003148    '          A4&B4&C4
and key111 like '%No ->   51053053    '          A5&B5&C5
```

all you need to do is just to paste all your number in column B and use it to generate the remaining.